# Diferença entre Render Partial e Render Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Gostaria de uma ajuda para entender melhor estes tipos de renderização com partial view.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Html.RenderAction**

- Este resultado de método será escrito diretamente para o fluxo de resposta response stream HTTP utilizado. Significa que o mesmo objeto utilizado como TextWriter  será também utilizado para a página e/ou template.
- Para este método, é preciso criar uma child action para renderizarmos a partial view.
- O Método RenderAction é útil quando os dados que são utilizados na partial view, são idenpendentes da view model correspondente.Exemplo: Em um blog para mostrar lista de categorias em cada página, gostaríamos de usar o método RenderAction já que a lista de categoria seria populada por uma model diferente.

  @{Html.RenderAction("Category","Home");}
- Este método é a melhor escolha quando se quer cachear a view uma partial view.
- Este método é mais rápido do que uma simples chamada de Action por exemplo, ja que a resposta também é utilizado diretamente via response stream HTTP, deixando a resposta mais rápida.

**Html.RenderPartial**

- Este resultado de método será escrito diretamente para o fluxo de resposta response stream HTTP utilizado. Significa que o mesmo objeto utilizado como TextWriter  será também utilizado para a página e/ou template.
- Este método “retorna” void.
- Simples de usar e não há necessidade de criar uma ação.
- O Método RenderPartial é útil quando os dados de exibição da partial view já estão view model. Por Exemplo : Em um blog, para mostrar os comentários de um artigo, gostaríamos de usar o método RenderPartial desde que o artigo com  os comentários já estão preenchidos previamente na view model.

  @{Html.RenderPartial("_Comments");}

Fonte Completa: http://codigosimples.net/2016/03/05/diferencas-entre-renderpartial-vs-renderaction-vs-partial-vs-action-no-mvc/